# ::before on open/close function

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I've created a function that will display on a wordpress website whether the business is open/closed depending on there hours.

Now I'm trying to add some CSS before the text that will display a red or green block indicating whether we're open or closed.

Here's is the css that I want to apply, but I'm not too sure what the best way of doing it would be? I previously tried adding the variable outputs into tags but It failed. Please could someone help me out with this.

https://codepen.io/vram1980/pen/Kyaie

**PHP**

```
add_shortcode( 'linestatus', 'line_status_handler' );
function line_status_handler( $atts ) { 
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        'open_time' => '09:00:00', 
        'closed_time' => '17:00:00', 
        'open_text' => 'our lines are open', 
        'closed_text' => 'our lines are closed', 
    ), $atts ) ); 

    if ( time() >= strtotime( $open_time ) && time() <= strtotime( $closed_time ) ) { 
        $output = $open_text; 
    } else { 
        $output = $closed_text; 
    } 
    return $output;
```

**Short code**

```
[linestatus] [linestatus open_time="08:00:00" closed_time="17:00:00" open_text="open" closed_text="closed"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your shortcode return text. Wrap return into some HTML, like `<div class="status_text"></div>` and style this block.

```
add_shortcode( 'linestatus', 'line_status_handler' );
function line_status_handler( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'open_time'   => '09:00:00',
        'closed_time' => '17:00:00',
        'open_text'   => 'our lines are open',
        'closed_text' => 'our lines are closed',
    ), $atts ) );

    if ( time() >= strtotime( $open_time ) && time() <= strtotime( $closed_time ) ) {
        $output = "<div class='status_text status_open'>$open_text</div>";
    } else {
        $output = "<div class='status_text status_closed'>$closed_text</div>";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Or add your pulsating dot to shortcode output.

Comment: Hi @MaximSarandi, do I just need to apply the css elements from the codepen to the new classes on the output text for this to apply now then

Comment: @Jordan Kellett, use example which i wrote in my answer and add all code you needed. you have all what you need to complete your task. Just complete him. Add other html to shortcode, add block with text. Use CSS to display text inline with greed dot. Use additional wrappers and class, colors.

Comment: Perfect! managed to get this done. thanks for your help.